# Save Image Path to NSDocuments then retrieve it as a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsfilemanager

I have an image picker controller that stores selected images into a directory. I am able to save the path fine but retrieving them causes a crash. I'm not sure if the code to save is wrong or the code to retrieve is wrong. This is the crash error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x1c484bc40'
```

Here's the code to retrieve the files and store in a `NSMutableArray`. This is where the crash happens. I need the results of the paths to be `UIImage` files.

```
- (void)loadCustomDesignGIFEdit:(TSPEventRepository *)record {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *arrSlidshowImg = @[].mutableCopy;
    NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",Dir, @"/Images/"];
    NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
     contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for (image in directoryContents) {
        [arrSlidshowImg addObject:image];
    }
    NSLog(@"ARRAY RESULT: %@", arrSlidshowImg);

    fourBySixBackgroundImageViewGIF.image = [arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:0];      
}
```

When I press on the button to call `loadCustomDesignGIFEdit` the log shows a correct path to the image I selected, but it crashes. I need it to save the path as an image with PNG representation into the `NSMutableArray`.

Here's the log result:

```
ARRAY RESULT: (
    "picName_IMG_7293.JPG",
    "picName_IMG_7294.JPG"
)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd advise against manually concatenation path strings like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", directory, @"/Images/"];`. I'd suggest `[directory stringAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"]`. `NSString` has provided a bunch of path and URL functions so you don't have to worry about where the slashes have to be inserted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a line that says:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]
```

That doesn't make sense, because `path` is the path of the folder, not of any particular image.

But your cryptic error stems from the following line of code:

```
fourBySixBackgroundImageViewGIF.image = [arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:0];
```

Unfortunately, `arrSlidshowImg` is an array of strings, not an array of images. So, when you supplied that as the `image` of your `UIImageView`, the error is cryptically telling you that it is trying to retrieve the `size` the image, but the `NSString` you supplied has no such method/property.

You probably meant:

```
NSString *filename = arrSlidshowImg[0];
NSString *imagePath = [path stringAppendingPathComponent:filename];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
fourBySixBackgroundImageViewGIF.image = image;
```

Comment: Two lines of code caused me an hour of grief. Thank you so much. That worked perfectly.